# Unit Test passes without check Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, bdd

I am using Node.js (noob in BDD). In my controller I have a function like so:

```
  var getUser = function(username, done) {
    console.log('prints');
    User.findOne({
      'local.username': username
    }, function (err, user) {
      console.log('doesn"t print');
      if (err) {
        return done('Oops, server error!', null);
      } else {
        return done(null, user);
      }
    });
  };
```

I am using Mocha and described a test block like so:

```
  describe('can be created only using a web interface', function () {
    describe('The user name should:', function () {
      it("be a valid email", function () {
        assert(common.isValidEmail(fakeuser.local.username));
      });
      it("not already exist in the database", function () {
        userController.getUser(fakeuser.local.username, function (err, user) {
          log.info('The user name is', user);
          //I would like to assert here. But user is always undefined.
        }());
      });
    });
  });
```

It seems like User.findOne is not working the way I expect it to since the test passes no matter what and the code inside doesn't even get executed. What am I missing?

NB: Calling the same function in other parts of the code works just fine.

### EDIT

The project is accessible here: https://github.com/attosol/nodeseed

The documentation (and project) is far from complete. Just do an npm install, and npm start followed by starting up your MongoDB (it will use the DB - nodeseed). Just signup using any valid email and find the activation URL in your log files.

Comment: do you export the get user function ? can you post the user controller ?

Comment: you aren't calling `done`, the test should never pass, it should timeout.

Comment: `it('test', function(done) { done(); })` will be a passing test. You should also use `assert` to throw assertions and prevent `done` from being called if your test doesn't pass.

Comment: I recommend that you play around with Mocha and the documentation a little more before using it to actually test your code.

Comment: @richardpringle thanks again for your pointer. It helped. There was an issue with my DB connection and my tests started timing out after your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to write something to compare against

```
it("not already exist in the database", function(done){
    var wasCalled = false;
    userController.getUser('my@email.com', function(err, user){
      console.log('doesn"t print');
      wasCalled = true;
    });
   expect(wasCalled).toBe(true);
  });
```

Comment: Tried it. wasCalled is still true. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Also, I would like to validate some values from user using the callback function. I am not sure why it is not calling it at all. It doesn't show any error either.